# mediaelement.js Wordpress audio not showing in mobile and tablet

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I am using the audio player, the audio element disappear in any of my browsers when width is 679px or less. Any idea why?

And How can I fix it?